# How to create half-height borders ?

Tags: tables

I am a noob when it comes to latex, I googled around but couldn't find something similar to what i'm looking for.

So, Basically, I'm trying to create a table with horizontal and vertical separators but without corners, like shown in this image

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! You could create a normal table and overlay the corners with white circles. Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question to give us something to start with?

Comment: Fastest would be to add \rule (for some fudged width) as an entry, possibly using \raisebox etc to adjust the vertical space.  Persoanlly, I would do the whole thing using \parboxes insead of tabulars.

Answer (score 0):

The `booktabs` package has the `\cmidrule` which can do what you need for horizontal lines.  I don't know a similarly "automated" solution for the vertical lines, but maybe you do not really need it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem} % to change separation in lists
\setlist{nosep} % no separation

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[t]{lcr}
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{\large \textbf{Projects}}         \\
  \cmidrule(l{.5cm}r{.5cm}){1-3}
  \textbf{Eyeshare } &       & \textsc{Co-Founder}     \\
  \multicolumn{3}{p{.5\linewidth}}{Helping visually impaired
  people see by connecting them to sighted volunteers} \\
  \textbf{Enki4kids} &       & \textsc{Developer}      \\
                     & \dots &                         \\
                     &       &                         \\
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{\large \textbf{Mini Bootcamps}}   \\
  \cmidrule(l{.5cm}r{.5cm}){1-3}
  \multicolumn{3}{p{.5\linewidth}}{
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Web development end2end
  \item Into ReactJS
  \item The JS way
  \end{itemize}
  }
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}[t]{lcr}
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{\large \textbf{Activities}}          \\
  \cmidrule(l{.5cm}r{.5cm}){1-3}
  \textbf{CSE}         &       & \textsc{Section manager} \\
  \multicolumn{3}{p{.5\linewidth}}{Monitoring and supervising
  projects, as well as teams}                             \\
  \textbf{GDG Algiers} &       & \textsc{Team Leader}     \\
                       & \dots &                          \\
                       &       &                          \\
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{\large \textbf{Presentations}}       \\
  \cmidrule(l{.5cm}r{.5cm}){1-3}
  \multicolumn{3}{p{.5\linewidth}}{
  \begin{itemize}
  \item WebDev
  \item ES6 the sexy JavaScript
  \item Think like a child: introduction to algorithms
  \end{itemize}
  }
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: partially spanning lines]